# How to show applicants list according to posted jobs id in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie in ruby on rails it's also my first ruby application.

I applied for a job according to posted_jobs_id as a jobseeker and
applied successfully.

Now I am a recruiter want to show specific applicants for specific
posted_jobs_id, but it's showing whole applicants when I click for
specific posted_jobs_id anyone can help me, please how can I write a
logic or solution for this?

My view file code:

```
<tbody>
    <% @applicants_view.each do | applicants | %>
       <tr>
          <td>
            <%= link_to user_path(:jobseeker_id =>applicants.jobseeker_id) %>
            <%= applicants.jobseeker.try(:first_name) %>
         </td>
         <td>
           <%= applicants.jobseeker.try(:year_of_experience) %>
         </td>

         <td>
          <%= applicants.expected_salary %>
        </td>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
 </tbody>
```

Thanks in Advanced for all!

Comment: In the controller you should set `@applicants_view` to smth like `Applicant.where(job_id: posted_jobs_id)`. This suggestion won’t work out of the box, since you likely have more complicated model, but the hint should be sufficient enough.

Comment: I mean your thinking is right, if you think deeply will be able to write answer  @mudasobwa

Comment: I’m not gonna write an answer, I already provided a valuable hint. Please show us your effort.

Comment: I  have tried like this    @applicants_view = AppliedJob.where(applied_jobs_id:posted_jobs_id) it's showing the below error   " undefined local variable or method `posted_jobs_id' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question! Want to share with the stack overflow community because it will be helpful for others.

I added in my controller:

> @applicants_view = AppliedJob.where(:posted_jobs_id =>
>   params[:posted_jobs_id])

My view file is same as question code.

Answer (score 0):

In start of your looping section, i.e.

> @applicants_view.each do | applicants |

it's not very clear what you have taken in **applicants_view** , but you need to modify it such a way that it only filters specific applicants who have viewed or applied for the job.

In backend models also you need to maintain records for job viewers (if you want to show the job viewers only)